# Twilio JS - Unable to do multiple calls with up to date tokens

Tags: javascript, twilio

I'm trying to use the JS SDK, so that I can make multiple calls during a short time period with different tokens. The tokens have an expiry time of around 10 seconds, so that the client expects a new token every time I make a new call request. The first outgoing voice call works as aspected, but the second returns me a 31002 error, even though I'm feeding him a new valid token. The problem only occurs with the JS SDK but not with the iOS or Android SDK.

Below the console output with more details

```
TOKEN: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6InNjb3BlOmNsaWVudDpvdXRnb2luZz9hcHBTaWQ9QVBjMDQxMDY3NDZlM2UxNDg3MzQwMGM4OTEwZTM3NzY4YyZhcHBQYXJhbXM9IiwiaXNzIjoiQUM3NTkxNjVjODlkYWNjZDZhYWVlMTc4NzQyMzFkODljYSIsImV4cCI6MTQ5MTMwMDA3Mn0.-TeNrT7pn-84X8nEEeP8DN959c_6M8MUJXBOUfIn7Ds
console.js:26 [Device] Setting up PStream
console.js:26 [WSTransport] Opening socket
console.js:26 [WSTransport] attempting to connect
console.js:26 [WSTransport] Socket opened
console.js:26 [PStream] Setting token and publishing listen
console.js:26 [Device] Stream is ready
console.js:26 [Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "have-local-offer"
console.js:26 Notification: twilio_client_connected
console.js:26 [Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "stable"
console.js:26 Twilio connected
console.js:26 [Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is "checking"
console.js:26 [Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is "completed"
console.js:26 [Connection] Disconnecting...
console.js:26 Twilio disconnected
console.js:26 [Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is "closed"
console.js:26 [Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "closed"
console.js:26 Notification: voice_call_status_no_answer
console.js:26 Object {params: Object, type: "voice_call_status_no_answer"}
console.js:26 Event fired: voice-call:status-no-answer
console.js:26 TOKEN: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6InNjb3BlOmNsaWVudDpvdXRnb2luZz9hcHBTaWQ9QVBjMDQxMDY3NDZlM2UxNDg3MzQwMGM4OTEwZTM3NzY4YyZhcHBQYXJhbXM9IiwiaXNzIjoiQUM3NTkxNjVjODlkYWNjZDZhYWVlMTc4NzQyMzFkODljYSIsImV4cCI6MTQ5MTMwMDExMn0.suJTJc0Sqa7akTsnAK7zo3IAYfhmr7vdw6jULDmBNd8
console.js:26 [Device] Found existing Device; using new token but ignoring options
console.js:26 [PStream] Setting token and publishing listen
console.js:26 [Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "have-local-offer"
console.js:26 [Connection] Received HANGUP from gateway
console.js:26 [Connection] Received an error from the gateway:
console.js:26 Objectcode: 31002connection: amessage: "Authentication is in progress, please try again later."__proto__: Object
console.js:26 Object {code: 31002, message: "Authentication is in progress, please try again later.", connection: a}
console.js:26 Twilio Error
console.js:26 Object {code: 31002, message: "Authentication is in progress, please try again later.", connection: a}
console.js:26 Object {code: 31002, message: "Authentication is in progress, please try again later.", connection: a}
console.js:26 Twilio Error
console.js:26 Object {code: 31002, message: "Authentication is in progress, please try again later.", connection: a}
console.js:26 [Connection] Disconnecting...
console.js:26 Twilio disconnected
console.js:26 [Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is "closed"
console.js:26 [Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "closed"
```

It would be great if anyone could help me.

And this is the code of my typescript class and the script I'm using to execute it:

```
  import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Twilio {

  device: any;

  token: string;

  connection: any;

  isConnected = false;

  isInitialised = false;

  Twilio = (<any>window).Twilio;

  public onReady = new EventEmitter<Object>();

  public onConnect = new EventEmitter<Object>();

  public onDisconnect = new EventEmitter<Object>();

  public onError = new EventEmitter<Object>();

  public onOffline = new EventEmitter<Object>();

  constructor(token: string) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.token = token;
      this.setup();
    }, 100);
  }

  public setup() {
    this.Twilio.Device.setup(this.token, { debug: true });

    if (!(<any>window).cordova) {
      this.Twilio.Device.audio.incoming(false);
      this.Twilio.Device.audio.disconnect(false);
      this.Twilio.Device.audio.outgoing(false);
    } else {
      this.Twilio.Device.sounds.incoming(false);
      this.Twilio.Device.sounds.disconnect(false);
      this.Twilio.Device.sounds.outgoing(false);
    }

    if (this.Twilio.Device.status() == 'ready') {
      this.onReady.emit({ isReady: true });
      this.isInitialised = true;
    }

    this.Twilio.Device.ready((device) => {
      this.onReady.emit(device);
      this.isInitialised = true;
    });

    this.Twilio.Device.offline(() => {
      this.onOffline.emit('');
    });

    this.Twilio.Device.connect((conn) => {
      this.isConnected = true;
      this.onConnect.emit('');
    });

    this.Twilio.Device.disconnect((conn) => {
      this.isConnected = false;
      this.onDisconnect.emit('');
    });

    this.Twilio.Device.error((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      this.onError.emit(error);
    });
  }

  connect(params) {
    if (!(<any>window).cordova) {
      this.connection = this.Twilio.Device.connect(params);
    } else {
      this.Twilio.Device.connect(params);
    }
  }

  disconnect() {
    if (!(<any>window).cordova) {
      try {
        this.Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
      } catch (error) {} finally {
        this.Twilio.Device.destroy();
      }
    } else {
      this.Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
    }
  }

  mute(param) {
    if (!(<any>window).cordova) {
      this.connection.mute(param);
    } else {
      this.Twilio.Connection.mute();
    }
  }

  speaker(param) {
    if ((<any>window).cordova) {
      this.Twilio.Connection.setSpeaker((param == true) ? 'on' : 'off');
    }
  }

  sendDigits(digit) {
    if (!(<any>window).cordova) {
      this.connection.sendDigits(digit);
    } else {
      this.Twilio.Connection.sendDigits(digit);
    }
  }
}

this.twilio = new Twilio(VoiceCallService.callToken);
this.twilio.onReady.subscribe(data => {
  if (!(<any>window).cordova) {
    this.twilio.connect({
      "PhoneNumber": this.voiceCall.targetNumber,
      "IsTranslated": (VoiceCallService.isTranslated) ? "yes" : "no",
      "UserId": Lockr.get('user_id'),
      "To": this.voiceCall.targetLanguage,
      "From": this.account.details.profile.language,
      "FriendId": this.voiceCall.friendId
    });
  }
});

this.twilio.onConnect.subscribe(data => {
  console.log('Twilio connected');
});

this.twilio.onDisconnect.subscribe(data => {
  console.log('Twilio disconnected');
});

this.twilio.onError.subscribe(data => {
  console.log('Twilio Error');
  console.log(data);
});

this.twilio.onOffline.subscribe(data => {
  console.log('Twilio offline');
});

if ((<any>window).cordova) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.twilio.connect({
      "PhoneNumber": this.voiceCall.targetNumber,
      "IsTranslated": (VoiceCallService.isTranslated) ? "yes" : "no",
      "UserId": Lockr.get('user_id'),
      "To": this.voiceCall.targetLanguage,
      "From": this.account.details.profile.language,
      "FriendId": this.voiceCall.friendId
    });
  }, 2000);
}
```

Cheers,
Marcel

Comment: Can you share the code you're using?

Comment: I've just added a code example. Btw, I've also tried using the .destroy function but it makes everything worse and creates even more problems. I'm able to make a second or third call, but it somehow keeps the connections stored and it generates an error msg when I'm using the mute function for example.

Comment: Hi @marcelgoya! It appears like there is some sort of race condition as the 31002 error says that the Authentication is in progress. A few more questions.
Where in your code do you actually initialize Twilio() and when are you fetching the token? 
What's the reason for the double "connect" in the bottom?
Are you using the Injector at any point to initialize the class? Else you should be able to drop the `@Injectable` decorator that is probably causing some side-effects.
You mentioned that using `destroy()` causes more problems. What are these problems?

Comment: Hi @philnash, I've managed to get the script running by using the .destroy after the disconnect event. I had the problem that the mute function did not work but I solved it by using the .activeConnection() function. In general, even using .destroy doesn't kill all connections. It's still caching the previous connections but it least generates a new one. I can see that it's caching the previous connections because the connected / disconnected event gets fired multiple times. Anyway, thanks for your help mate :)

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem, have opened a ticket with Twilio. After 2-3 multiple calls I start getting this error
 Authentication is in progress, please try again later